# What does "screw things up for you" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *The Kissing Booth 2 (2020)*, Elle is not impressed with her dance partner, Marco:

> Elle: Oh, my God! The big deal is that the competition is literally in
> four weeks -and the routine is a complete nightmare!
>
> Marco: I think you're exaggerating.
>
> Elle: No, listen, if you don't want to take this seriously, we
> should just  call it off.
>
> Marco: Okay, time out. So I'm using every free hour I have, practicing
> into the night for this competition that you asked me to help you
> with, just so I could **screw  things up for you**?

What does "screw things up for you" mean?

I heard "screw sb up", but what does this word mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Make things go all wrong.* He is sarcastically asking whether she thinks that, as he has spent so much time practising, he really doesn't want them to succeed.